# Error while installing nodejs 18 on linux

Tags: node.js, linux

While trying to install node js on linux I'm getting below error:

0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/28.7 MB of archives.
After this operation, 187 MB of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 378127 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../nodejs_18.16.1-deb-1nodesource1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nodejs (18.16.1-deb-1nodesource1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/nodejs_18.16.1-deb-1nodes
ource1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
trying to overwrite '/usr/share/systemtap/tapset/node.stp', which is also in pa
ckage libnode72:amd64 12.22.9~dfsg-1ubuntu3
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/nodejs_18.16.1-deb-1nodesource1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar issue. I was able to solve the issue using the following command below.

`sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/nodejs_18.16.1-deb-1nodesource1_amd64.deb`